# Views in Relativelayout inside a Fragment have extra spaces

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm working on my landscape layout which is a `RelativeLayout` with a `CardView`, two `ImageViews` and a simple `TextView`. On the preview in Android Studio it looks exactly like what I want but if I test it on my real device it looks strange because there are always extra spaces.

This is the preview in [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?hl=es-419):
[image]

And it looks like this on a real device:
[image]

Here is the layout file:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res 
    /android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="de.udacity.dk.cleverdroid.ui.QuizActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/question_and_answers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/iv_back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_question"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="This is a question" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_singlechoice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/rg_singlechoice"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_choice1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="Android" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_choice2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="Android" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_choice3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="Android" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_choice4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="Android" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_next"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_back"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="This is the answer"
        tools:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp"
        android:text="@string/quiz_back"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
        android:text="@string/quiz_next"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The layout will be inflated into the `Fragment` container of my `Activity` which looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"></FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I first thought it is because of the included `AppBar` of the related `Activity`, so I removed it. But that does not solve the problem.
Where did this extra space come from?

Comment: Test changing android:layout_height="match_parent" on RadioGroup.

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it after hours of headaches.
In my `Activity` I was referring to the wrong activity layout which has 24dp of padding in its `Fragment` container. After referring to the posted activity layout without any padding it works. This was a really easy mistake.